# Verificar qual pagina acessada anteriormente e caso positivo exibir algo

Tags: php, javascript, cross-browser

Preciso fazer uma verificação, que se a origem não for vindo do [**facebook.com**](http://www.facebook.com) não poderá mostrar um determinado código.

Apenas pessoas que vindas do [**facebook.com**](http://www.facebook.com) poderão ver o determinado código, caso venha de outro link, verá outro código diferente.

> Não tenho conhecimentos em PHP, apenas em C#, mas consigo entender bem
>   a estrutura... (são similares)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o host do referrer é o facebook.com. A função [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) retorna um array contendo informações da URL. O índice `host` do array que é retornado pela função conterá *somente* o host do endereço e nada mais.

```
$info = parse_url($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);

if(strpos($info['host'], 'facebook.com') !== false) {
    // veio do facebook!
} else {
    // não veio do facebook
}
```

O problema é que o facebook usa HTTPS e o navegador irá enviar o referrer *somente* se seu link também for HTTPS.

Se seu site não possui certificado SSL, uma outra alternativa é usar algum parâmetro na URL para identificar a fonte do acesso.

Comment: mas esse == não vai retornar algo do tipo http:// e dar um false? não teria que ser algo do tipo 'conter' facebook

Comment: @Dorathoto Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Vou colocar aqui em baixo `dois` `links` que lhe podem ajudar a resolver a sua questão/dúvida.

[**1º LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953389/making-a-web-page-visible-only-when-user-comes-from-a-specific-page-or-link) (pelo que percebi da sua questão/duvida, este link é o que lhe deverá dar uma maior ajuda.)

[**2º LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015634/detect-if-user-comes-back-go-back-event-or-if-can-go-forward)

> nao copiei o código de ambos os links porque cada autor merece os
>   seus créditos !

Comment: show, acho q o primeiro link resolve, com o $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: Se quiser pode coloca esta resposta certa, para servir de referência para dúvidas similares.

Comment: @thecreator Você pode colocar o código aqui e informar a fonte deles. Se no futuro algum desses sites mudar de endereço ou sair do ar a sua resposta acaba ficando sem utilidade por conter apenas links e nenhum conteúdo.